# get Y position percentage programmatically

Tags: android

I'm doing some translate animations with a view. I'm trying both ways: By xml and programmatically.

This is how I have defined the translation by xml:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <translate android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="-70%" android:duration="1000"/>
</set>
```

This way it works fine, but I've realized that I better need the programmatically way as using the animationListener I can define actions to occurr when the animation finishes.

This is how I do it programmatically:

```
slide_up = new TranslateAnimation(valuesContainer.getX(),
            valuesContainer.getX(),
            valuesContainer.getY(),
            valuesContainer.getY() - 70);
    slide_up.setDuration(1000);
    slide_up.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            //SOMETHING HAPPENS
        }
    });
```

The problem comes when defining the `fromYDelta` and `toYDelta` values (the image just moves in the Y axis). In the xml, I do it using percentages (%) and it works the way I need, but I don't know how to    set the values this same way but programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come to a solution combining both of this methods.

I define the animation in a xml like this, called f.e. slide_up_anim.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <translate android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="-70%" android:duration="1000"/>
</set>
```

And then, I set the AnimationListener for this animation this way:

```
slide_up = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.slide_up_anim);

slide_up.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
```

This way I can define the fromYDelta and toYDelta in percentage, and also listen for animation events.