# How to specify the value %parent programatically in android?

Tags: java, android, spring, animation, parent

If we analyze the XML code:

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
  android:duration="1000"
  android:fromXDelta="0"
  android:fromYDelta="0"
  android:toXDelta="0"
  android:toYDelta="80%p" />
```

Can be achieved using the same code of programatically :

```
TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(
    Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0,
    Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.8);
animatedView.setDuration(1000);
      animatedView.startAnimation(animation);
```

How do i should write, "**0.8" or "0.8f" or "0.08" or "0.8p**" ? Because I want the value become 80% of the parent views.

Comment: have you try `0.8f` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26058887/get-y-position-percentage-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the doc:

```
 /**
     * Constructor to use when building a TranslateAnimation from code
     * 
     * @param fromXType Specifies how fromXValue should be interpreted. One of
     *        Animation.ABSOLUTE, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, or
     *        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT.
     * @param fromXValue Change in X coordinate to apply at the start of the
     *        animation. This value can either be an absolute number if fromXType
     *        is ABSOLUTE, or a percentage (where 1.0 is 100%) otherwise.
     * @param toXType Specifies how toXValue should be interpreted. One of
     *        Animation.ABSOLUTE, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, or
     *        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT.
     * @param toXValue Change in X coordinate to apply at the end of the
     *        animation. This value can either be an absolute number if toXType
     *        is ABSOLUTE, or a percentage (where 1.0 is 100%) otherwise.
     * @param fromYType Specifies how fromYValue should be interpreted. One of
     *        Animation.ABSOLUTE, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, or
     *        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT.
     * @param fromYValue Change in Y coordinate to apply at the start of the
     *        animation. This value can either be an absolute number if fromYType
     *        is ABSOLUTE, or a percentage (where 1.0 is 100%) otherwise.
     * @param toYType Specifies how toYValue should be interpreted. One of
     *        Animation.ABSOLUTE, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, or
     *        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT.
     * @param toYValue Change in Y coordinate to apply at the end of the
     *        animation. This value can either be an absolute number if toYType
     *        is ABSOLUTE, or a percentage (where 1.0 is 100%) otherwise.
     */
    public TranslateAnimation(int fromXType, float fromXValue, int toXType, float toXValue,
            int fromYType, float fromYValue, int toYType, float toYValue) {

        mFromXValue = fromXValue;
        mToXValue = toXValue;
        mFromYValue = fromYValue;
        mToYValue = toYValue;

        mFromXType = fromXType;
        mToXType = toXType;
        mFromYType = fromYType;
        mToYType = toYType;
    }
```

toYValue Change in Y coordinate to apply at the end of the
             animation. This value can either be an absolute number if toYType
         is ABSOLUTE, or a percentage (where 1.0 is 100%) otherwise.

you should give **0.8f**.